# Using calculated variable in windows batch file as command line parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to calculate variable value in FOR loop and then reuse it as command line parameter when calling executable file.
I managed to calculate the variable, but i can't pass is to exe file

Full code:

SetParameters.bat

```
SET PAYLOAD_SIZE=1024 
SET OPERATIONS_COUNT=20
SET THREADS=8
SET BULKSIZE=200
```

And the executed bat file

```
call 0_SetParameters.bat
SET MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR %%n IN (1 2 4 8) do (
@SET /a MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID+=%OPERATIONS_COUNT%
echo !MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!
Launcher.exe -P:%PAYLOAD_SIZE% -O:%OPERATIONS_COUNT% -N:test1 -T:%%n -BULKSIZE:%BULKSIZE% -MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID:%MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID%
)
```

echo !MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID! - prints calculated value that i need, but when i try to pass parameter to exe file variable is equal 0 (initial variable value).

I also tried

```
Launcher.exe -P:%PAYLOAD_SIZE% -O:%OPERATIONS_COUNT% -N:test1 -T:%%n -BULKSIZE:%BULKSIZE% -MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID:!MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!
```

but this passes string "!MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!" and not the numeric value.
So how can i use this variable when calling exe file?

UPDATE: 
Ok, i understood what was happening here. Actually everything worked, executable was called with calculated parameter, but output to console was printing -MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID:!MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!

So correct way to call executable is

```
Launcher.exe -P:%PAYLOAD_SIZE% -O:%OPERATIONS_COUNT% -N:test1 -T:%%n -BULKSIZE:%BULKSIZE% -MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID:!MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!
```

Comment: `!MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!` <-- this is correct.  Double check your spelling of the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample that proves your code works: it doesn't use the %%n variable as you code doesn't use it.

```
@echo off
set OPERATIONS_COUNT=5
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%n IN (1 2 4 8) do (
SET /a MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID+=OPERATIONS_COUNT
echo !MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!
echo Launcher.exe -MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID:!MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!
)
pause
```

Comment: i updated question, i need %%n parameter and triple checked parameter name. your example works, but i still can't understand what is wrong with mine =(

Comment: Ok, i understood what was happening here. Actually everything worked, executable was called with calculated parameter, but output to console was printing -MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID:!MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID!

Comment: Your changed batch file still needs this changed with exclamation marks `-MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID:%MAX_EMPLOYEE_ID%`